# How to import a non-maven JAR using maven-external-dependency-plugin and make it a compile-time dependency?

Tags: maven-3

Has anyone used the [Maven External Dependency plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-external-dependency-plugin/source/browse/trunk/maven-external-dependency-plugin-test/pom.xml) to import a non-maven external JAR as compile-time dependency? The example given in this link is not helping me, as it is not getting executed before compile phase? Is there a way to import the JAR and make it a maven artifact as well as a dependency before the compile phase of the project? Any examples will be helpful? Is it even possible to deploy and declare it as a compile-time dependency? In my project, the compiler plugin seems to run before it and compile fails. I want this plugin to run before that.

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.savage7.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-external-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <stagingDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/dependencies/
                </stagingDirectory>
                <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
                <skipChecksumVerification>false</skipChecksumVerification>
                <force>false</force>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.thoughtworks</groupId>
                        <artifactId>customer-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <downloadUrl>file://${customerapp.path}</downloadUrl>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Maven output (removed project name and code location for confidentiality):

```
--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ ... ---
[INFO] Deleting ....
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ... ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory ....
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ ... ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to ...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, I want this maven-external-dependency=plugin to run before compile step and for the compile step to pick it up as dependency.

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: Simply start using a repository manager like Artifactory, Nexus, Archiva and install that artifact into the repository manager and done.

Comment: You can pull your external dependency into your local machine and then install the jar into your local maven repo with mvn:install-file command . After this you will be able to refer your jar in pom.